# Could you extract energy from a rotational white hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, white-holes

I understand it is possible to do it in a black hole, and its also possible to reach the event horizon of a black hole and increase its size.

But in a white hole, no wave (electromagnetic or gravitational) can reach the white hole's event horizon. So, if you apply the penrose process to a white hole, would you be affecting the speed of rotation near its event horizon?

Comment: Anything is possible with white holes

Answer (score 1):

A white hole is the time-reverse of a black hole.  So, a "white hole penrose process" necessarily is the time-reverse of the ordinary penrose process, which would be a particle absorbing a wave or particle coming from the event horizon, leaving the white hole "spun up".

If this sounds weird, it's because it is weird, in the same way that the advanced solutions of Maxwell's equations are weird.

Comment: Could you explain further this case?

Comment: @Manuel: what's to explain?  you literally just take the "forward" black hole solution, time-reverse the paths, pretend that it's your new "forward" time direction, and you have a valid path in a white hole spacetime.  That's in fact what a white hole is.  So, the white hole emits a particle that has negative mass relative to infinity, it picks up net spin, and the negative mass accelerates the nearby particle, exactly the opposite of the black hole penrose process.

Comment: @safesphere: the time reverse of a closed orbit is a closed orbit.  A white hole horizon is absolutely repulsive, though.

Comment: @safesphere: you cannot radially fall into a white hole.  You radially fall out of it.  The white hole singularity lives in the past of all timelike and null orbits that intersect it, just as the black hole singularity lives in the future of all timelike and null orbits.

A white hole is the time reverse of a black hole, full stop.  That's what it is.  it's an artifact of the fact that einstein's equations have time reversal symmetry, but an object falling into a black hole does not have a reverse process unless you "reverse the horizon" somehow.

Comment: @safesphere: look at the Kruskal diagram of the spacetime with both holes.  There's no ambiguity or puzzle here.

Comment: @safesphere: If you're going to reject something as basic as the existence of an atlas of smooth coordinate systems over a semi-reimannian manifold and extended spacetimes, then you're not talking about standard physics anymore.  You are embedding deep philosophical assumptions and claims that are not standard in the study of general relativity and positing them as obvious facts.  This is a set of basic assumptions in differential topology.

Comment: And if you're going to take your perspective, it's every bit as valid to just say that white holes don't exist, since they are only solutions that exist thanks to extended spacetime solutions.

Comment: @safesphere the schwarzschild manifold is not singular on the horizon.  It just is not.  Making assertions about "the physical schwarzschild manifold" is not helping your case.  I have thought logically for myself.  Again, I have thought for two seconds about differential topology and understand the notion of an atlas over a manifold.Schwarzschild coordinates exist as a patch on the extended Kruskal spacetime.You don't have coordinate transformations between causally disconnected parts of the manifold for the same reason that you dont' ahve nonsingular transformations between rindler observers

Comment: But the Penrose process implies the absortion of a particle, and in white holes, no particle can enter the event horizon of the white hole!

Comment: @Manuel: yes, the time-reverse is radiation/particles leaving the horizon and getting absorbed by the orbing object.

Comment: That means that you could not extract rotational energy from a white hole, because nothing from outside its event horizon can go inside, in order to leave the horizon and contribute to the penrose process!

Comment: @Manuel : that's kind of the content of my answer.  the time-reversed penrose process for a white hole is the opposite of the penrose process for a black hole.